# c++ BST and file handling

Tags: c++

i am interested in creating a car register program:

menu for user to add, delete, find, edit(change a particular detail about the car) a car and view all the cars. this is then stored in memory using a binary search tree. all the cars are to be written out from memory into a csv file. also when loading the system it should read all the cars back in

car has 2 types petrol and electric. 
every car has attributes car id, owner, make, model, numberplate
a petrol car has attributes miles, topup
an electric car has attributes power, miles

```
class car
{
string id
string owner
string make 
string model
string numberplate
virtual getkey()//gets key being searched etc.
readfile();
writefile();
};

class petrol : public car
{
string miles 
string topup
};

class electric : public car
{
string power
string miles
};


data structure:

class node
{
car *ptr
node *left
node *right
};

class tree
{
///insert delete etc.
};
```

would this be a practical class design and what functions might need to be included?

Comment: A more practical design would be to use a template for the data field of the BST.

Comment: please could you elaborate, so i would have to template the functions as well?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with initial BST and Linked List implementations is that they either force you to use a specific data type or inherit from that data type (such as yours).  If I want a BST for fruit, I can't use your tree, because your tree is dedicated to cars.

I suggest an abstract node class and deriving your data classes from the node class:

```
struct Node
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Node>  left;
    boost::shared_ptr<Node>  right;

    // Interface functions for descendants
    virtual bool  is_less_than(boost::shared_ptr<Node> other_node) const = 0;
    virtual bool  is_equal_to(boost::shared_ptr<Node> other_node) const = 0;
};
```

I still believe the best design is to use a template:

```
template <class User_Data_Type>
class Node
{
  public:
    boost::shared_ptr<Node>  left;
    boost::shared_ptr<Node>  right;
    User_Data_Type           m_data;
};
```

Comment: @user2355449: if the answer is useful, please click on the check mark.